# Jackson read-only property in method

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

I need to exposes a property in my json that will be processed in the getter method.

The class:

```
public class Configuracao{

   private String departamento;

   public String getDepartamento(){/**getter code**/}

   public void setDepartamento(String departamento){/**setter code**/}

   public String getDepartamentos(){/***Some logic code***/}

}
```

The json that got in front: `{departamento: "Lote", departamentos: "Lotes"}`

Works fine in serialization, but when my front-end post the json back, jackson throws a unrecognized field exception caused by 'departamentos'. How can I tell that I just want to 'departamentos' be serialized by the method value and be ignored in deserialization. I tried `@JsonIgnoreProperty`, `@JsonGetter` and `@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)` on the method but nothing works.

Comment: I think https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not explains your case under point 7.

Comment: Should I have a empty setDepartamentos to be marked as ignorable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuracao c = new Configuracao();
        c.setDepartamento("D1");

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(c);
        System.out.println(json);
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Configuracao.class));
    }
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Configuracao {

    private String departamento;

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    public String getDepartamentos() {
        return departamento + " " + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Configuracao{" +
                "departamento='" + departamento + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"departamento":"D1","departamentos":"D1 0.8600092703789755"}
Configuracao{departamento='D1'}
```

`JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY` should also works:

```
class Configuracao {

    private String departamento;

    public String getDepartamento() {
        return departamento;
    }

    public void setDepartamento(String departamento) {
        this.departamento = departamento;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    public String getDepartamentos() {
        return departamento + " " + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Configuracao{" +
                "departamento='" + departamento + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

with above test works as expected.

If you have more classes like this and fields to ignore, you can disable globally feature `DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

Everything was tested with version [2.9.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.9.9)

Comment: `ignoreUnknown = true` did the trick but `JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY` didn't. I expected jackson should have a manner to handle this situation without ignore annotations. But that's it for today.

Comment: @josev.junior, Which version of `Jackson` do yo  use? In version `2.9.9` all shown solution work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `departamentos` property in `Configuracao` class.

```
public class Configuracao{
   private String departamento;
   private String departamentos;
   //omitted getter/setter
}
```

Comment: That's is the only way to solve? I didn't want to create a `departamentos` property because it is the processed `departamento`. I just want to serialize (and not deserialize) without define the property.